# Photoshop CS6: cleanig the list of available scripts

Tags: photoshop

Anyone knows how to manage the list of scripts in Menu>File? I have a lot of scripts in the list, so I'd like to clean-up it.

Thanks.

Comment: Delete some of your scripts in the Photoshop/Presets/Scripts directory and then restart Photoshop.

Comment: Mark, I'm using that "dirty solution". The problem is... if I want to test several scripts i'll quickly get a huge list again. I'm looking for something more "gentle" and professional. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I never put scripts I'm testing in there in the first place.  I mostly just open and run them through the debugger, or I believe you can just drag them from your desktop (or wherever you have them stored) onto the Photoshop window and it will run them automatically as well.